# How could AI solve planet's major problems?

Tags: applications

I had been reading that AI could solve planet's major problems. How could it be done? For example, how exactly could AI be applied to address climate change? What are examples of applications of AI to solve these problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's indeed a lot of research work being done in this field.

Here are a few ways in which AI can help/is helping in fighting major problems:

### Climate change

- Identify deforestation and the rate at which it's happening using computer vision and help in fighting back based on how critical the rate is.The World Resources Institute had entered into a [partnership](https://www.wired.com/2015/04/using-smart-satellites-to-monitor-deforestation-from-space/) with Orbital Insight on this.

### Protecting Nature

- Researchers and institutes are [using](http://www.grevyszebratrust.org/stripe-recognition.html) computer vision to accurately identify total remaining members of extremely threatened species to observe their behavior and patterns that can help in protecting them, keep track and monitor at an individual level.
- Environmental/ Research agencies are trying to [detect sounds](http://www.birds.cornell.edu/page.aspx?pid=2713) from ocean audio from which they can identify inhabiting fish and route the ships away from threatened habitats.

### Energy

- [Optimise energy usage](https://deepmind.com/blog/deepmind-ai-reduces-google-data-centre-cooling-bill-40/) based on consumption in big companies to save energy for public use and in turn reduce energy overall demands on the grid.
- Predict the demand for energy and ensure continuous supply matching the demand. For example, Google's Deepmind is in [talks](https://www.ft.com/content/27c8aea0-06a9-11e7-97d1-5e720a26771b) National Grid of UK on this.

Of course, these ideas might look too tiny or too broad at first sight, but I feel taking one step at a time and then quickly expanding the ideas into wider areas would be the way to go, like how DeepMind is doing it in the area of energy. Other areas like education, transportation, and healthcare are seeing lots of activity with the involvement of AI too.

For further reading, here's what World Economic Forum [thinks](https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2017/02/5-global-problems-that-ai-could-help-us-solve/) about how AI can help solve world's problems.