# How do I segment each part of a DICOM image?

Tags: computer-vision, matlab, image-segmentation

As I'm beginner in image processing, I am having difficulty in segmenting all the parts in [DICOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM) image.

Currently, I'm applying [*watershed algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_(image_processing)), but it segments only that part that has tumour.

I have to segment all parts in the image. Which algorithm will be helpful to perform this task?

The image below contains the tumour.

[image]

This image is the actual DICOM image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I looked at some picture from DICOM, and it seems that these images usually don't have many local minima, so I guess that's why watershed isn't optimal.
However, it seems that in DICOM the color gradients are often strong, so I suggest to use techniques that works well with gradients:

- Direct Gradient computations, either convolutional gradients or morphological gradients (selects shape of your different objects)
- Normalized Cut on Similarity Graphs

If you want to know more about these you can read [this post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/7617/2444).